# How to detect SPFieldLookupValue from an SPListItem?

Tags: splistitem

I have a SPListItem, with different fields (string, lookup, etc), that I have to iterate them and do different actions depending of the type.

How can I detect if value is type String or type Lookup?

```
  value = spListItem["nameField"];  // is string or lookup?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the C# is operation. Ie.

```
if (value is SPFieldLookupValue) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string tipoCampo = itemCollection.Fields[ColumnsAssignation.ComboText].TypeAsString;
if (tipoCampo == "Lookup") {}
```